# How to view upload status?

Tags: 7.5, uploading

I recorded a long video and I am trying to share on Facebook, I would like to keep track of the upload progress, but I don't know where I can check it.

Is there a way to check the upload status?

Answer (score 1):

It will show in the Picture Hub in the bottom of the first section. It will show Photo uploads waiting for Wi-Fi to upload too.

Comment: Is it for wp8? I am using 7.5, I searched every corner on the Pictures APP and didn't find it. (WP 7.5, HTC Titan)

Comment: Sorry. Yes, this is the behavior of WP8. I don't know if WP7.5 does the same.

Comment: oh, ok thanks. I will handle big uploads from my pc after syncing with Zune. I guess I can only hope for a udpate. Anyway, thanks for letting me know about it on wp8.